# Reporting Period PHP

Tags: php, date

I have a php script that reports reporting period between Friday (start) and Thursday (end).  When It hits friday it doesn't skip over to the next reporting period like it should.

```
    $dates    = [];
    $end      = new DateTimeImmutable('Friday');
    $start    = $end->modify('-1 weeks');
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1W');
    $period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

    foreach ($period as $date) {
       $wednesday = $date->modify('Thursday');
       $dates[] = sprintf('%s - %s%s', $date->format('D j M'), $wednesday->format('D j M'), PHP_EOL);
    }
    $dates = array_reverse($dates);
    foreach ($dates  as $week) {
       $data .= "<tr><td><strong>Reporting Period:</strong></td><td>".$week."</td></tr>";
    }
```

I am not a PHP developer and I am stuck in how to get this working correctly.  Any assistance would be great.

Comment: Is the variable `$data` defined anywhere? I get `NOTICE Undefined variable: data`, which means that the concatenation is applied to a variable that doesn't exist. Maybe add `$data = '';` after dates at the top.

Comment: It is defined elsewhere, the issue is that when Friday comes it does not click over to the next reporting period.  On Saturday it will kick over, even though Friday is the first day of the reporting period.

Answer (score 0):

Just switch the end day if its Friday:

```
if (date('N') == 5) {
    $startday = 'next Friday';
} else {
    $startday = 'Friday';
}
$end = new DateTimeImmutable($startday);
```

Comment: Thank you that worked a treat I just made a slight adjustment because declaring $startday in the DateTimeImmutable caused a critical error.  This is what I did:'''  if (date('N') == 5) {
  $end = new DateTimeImmutable('next Friday');
 } else {
    $end = new DateTimeImmutable('Friday');
 }'''

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me for the above code:

```
if (date('N') == 5) { 
     $end = new DateTimeImmutable('next Friday'); 
} else { 
     $end = new DateTimeImmutable('Friday'); 
}
```